# Google app engine, multiple languages

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, scala

i'm working on on a project with DJango but i'm also thinking about going the Jython route.  By doing so...since i'll be using the java instance instead of cpython wouldn't I be able to use java, scala, ruby and other other languages that run on top of the jvm if need be?

Comment: Why so many languages?  What's the point?

Comment: the point is....how big of a toolbox can i carry along with me.  while 100% sure that you won't use every tool it's great to have options.

Comment: -1: What?  Libraries are logically equivalent to tools in a toolbox. One programming language is sufficient.  Would you **seriously** use java, scala, ruby and  some other random language?  You're just creating valueless complexity in order to use many programming languages.  Any one language will do everything.

Comment: All of them...nah.  I WOULD like the freedom of using scala and python together though.

Comment: "Freedom"?  Hardly.  Confusion for all the maintainers and supporters who come after you.  Please don't create a pile of junk that folks have to rewrite.

Comment: wow...so angry. No where did I say I would use every language under the SUN.  Absolutely no where.  2 languages in a project however...isn't bad.  You use whatever is best.  I do agree that you should aim for making maintenance as crystal clear s possible.

Answer (score 1):

[Scala works on GAE](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/1826).

[So does Ruby](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-jruby/).

If you want to know about other JVM languages, google search for `google app engine` followed by the name of the language of interest.

---

Also see [this page](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/web/will-it-play-in-app-engine?pli=1).

Comment: what i mean is lets say python is my language but there's a piece that simply would work faster written in ...scala.  could i also include scala code in the same project since they're all running on the jvm.  I have access to any and all languages on the jvm if i go the java route, correct?

Comment: @Uruhara747 It is possible to run Java (+ other JVM languages) or Python for the same application but they must be in separate versions of your app. They will share the same datastore and memcache services.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how good the Jython Java Interop is. But with Clojure you can generate Java classes pretty easy if it is nessesary (not sure). Clojure is really good for GAE.

There are nice librarys, blogs and applications. Like a DSL to work with the Datastore.

Librarys:

- http://github.com/smartrevolution/clj-gae-datastore
- http://github.com/r0man/appengine-clj

Look at this blog:

- http://elhumidor.blogspot.com/2009/04/clojure-on-google-appengine.html
- http://compojureongae.posterous.com/
- http://www.hackers-with-attitude.com/

This is written in Clojure with the GAE:

- http://the-deadline.appspot.com/